# RichFaces jsFunction cancelled ajax results in being redirected to error

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have a basic a4j:jsFunction that happens to run at the time when user could manually navigate away from current page. This always results in being redirected to error.jsf if that ajax was still in-flight.

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="callMyBean" actionListener="#{testController.doTest}" />
```

How can I swallow that error?

Simple steps to reproduce: Execute the jsFunction, pause the doTest() in debugger and type a new url in the browser. Instead of navigating to the new page, you will end up on Error.jsf

Comment: Looking at jsf.js there is logic to handle errors by sending a new request to error: AjaxEngine.req.onComplete(){ .. sendError(req.xmlReq, req.context, "httpError");..}   What can be done to avoid this as I choose?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was registering a listener on jsf.ajax object. I completely forgot about that.

```
jsf.ajax.addOnError(function(data) {
  ..
  window.location.replace("error.jsp");
}
```

So now I look at data.status to watch out for "httpError" flag and skip the error.jsp